# Import and Initializing another File in VS Code Python

Tags: python, python-import

I want to initialize another the Webscraper Class from the Webscraper File.
I have read on multiple pages that from Webscraper import Webscraper should be it.
Error Message can be found below.

Folder Structure:

```
DataScienceProject2(Folder Name) 
     __init__.py
     main.py
     Webscraper.py
```

First init Code:

```
__all__ = ["main", "Webscraper"]
```

main.py Code:

```
from Webscraper import Webscraper
if __name__ == '__main__':
    webscraper = Webscraper()
```

Webscraper.py Code:

```
class Webscraper: 
      def __init__(self): code to execute when being initialized
```

Error Message:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'Webscraper' from 'Webscraper' (c:\*PrivateInfo*\DataScienceProject2\Webscraper.py)
```

Comment: In the main file you never import the Webscraper class, is that intended? Also I tried reproducing your project, then I added `from Webscraper import Webscraper` ath the top of the main.py file and running python3 main.py works for me. Are ypu running your project differently?

Comment: When using vscode open the entire project tree with file > open.

Comment: Metteo thanks I just forgot the import in this post. @KeeganM thanks that helped.